# What's next after first 5 months and 700 points?

Tags: learning, beginner, study, planning

I started playing chess in July. I was at a 600 rating on Chess.com for a month. I started playing seriously in August and have played regularly (at least a few blitz and rapid games everyday). Currently, I am rated 1300 on Chess.com after 800 games(10 minutes). I seem to have moved past my blundering days (although still blunder every now and then). I also play shorter games on lichess (rated 1400 on blitz).

I haven't really read any literature yet. I started reading Logical chess by Chernev. I play the games out on the board and they are fascinating but I don't see how I can improve with them. Also, I do puzzles on lichess frequently. I haven't seen any significant changes in my thinking process recently when I play games. What's the next thing I should do?

My goal really is to be able to create and execute longer plans in the game while being able to read the opponents plan and defend. I was told this corresponds to the ~1900 rating range, so that would be my target (rating wise) by the end of 2019.

Comment: Although you've gained a lot of rating points in the last few months, note that the rating progress will not be linear and that going from 1300 to 1900 is a lot more difficult and time-consuming than going from 600 to 1300. Getting to 1900 shouldn't be impossible with good practice, but be prepared that it may take longer than a year.

Comment: Also I recommend, don't play intensely more than 3 days a week, initially. Or you'll feel burnt out,and won't have much cognitive capacity left for other things in life.

Answer (score 4):

This is an open-end question. My recommendation is join serious face-to-face tournaments where you play games at the classical time control. Playing blitz is fun, but not a good idea for learning chess.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're Magnus Carlsen, you pretty much never move past the blundering stage. They just tend to be smaller blunders.

In addition to the advice in [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/23286/9025), I highly recommend analyzing your own games. Those are two of the things that helped me jump from around a 1400 USCF rating, to eventually breaking 1700, before dropping back down to my current rating of ~1600. That still took me a few years, though, mostly because I was usually one of the two lowest rated players in the small local tournaments I played.

If you can get a coach, or even a stronger friend to train with in person, that is very helpful as well. They can more accurately pinpoint exactly what you need to work on to improve.